# how to passing value from inputbox to reducer in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I just create a simple redux project,
and I facing the new thing I didn't know, cz Im new in reactJS, it is how to passing value from reducer
in order to replace the globalstate with the new value i've passed,

```
    //Global State
    const initialstate = {
       nameOrder : ''
    }

   // Reducer Action
   const rootReducer = (state = initialstate ,action) => 
   {
    console.log(action.value)
    if(action.type === 'CHANGE'){
       return{
      ...state,
         nameOrder : action.value

        }
      }
    return state;
  }

//Store
const storeroot = createStore(rootReducer);
```

and this my code to pass the value I want

```
render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div>
                <Card width="50%">
                    <CardHeader>
                        {this.props.order}
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Form inline>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label  >Desc1</Label>
                                <Input onChange={this.HandleChange1} />
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label  >Desc2</Label>
                                <Input onChange={this.HandleChange2} />
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label>Harga</Label>
                                <Input onChange={this.onChangePrice}/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <Button onClick={this.props.ubah}>Submit</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </CardBody>
                    <CardFooter>
                    </CardFooter>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }


const mapStatetoProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        order : state.totalOrder
    }
}

const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        ubah:() => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE',value:this.state.desc1})
    }
}
export default connect(mapStatetoProps,mapDispatchtoProps)(Addform)
```

in mapDispatchtoProps  **this.state.desc1** its throw error, can anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple.

```
 ubah:() => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE',value:this.state.desc1})
```

In the statement above the this pointer is not defined. You have to pass the value as parameter.

```
 ubah:(description) => dispatch({type: 'CHANGE',value:description})
```

When you use the function for event handling, you have to call it like the code below:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.props.ubah(this.state.desc1)}>Submit</Button>
```